# How to connect a simple_port to a concatenation of VHDL signals?

Tags: vhdl, specman

I would like to have an out simple_port bound to multiple VHDL `std_logic_vectors`.
More specifically , i want to connect a 10 bit simple port to two 5 bit buses so that they both construct a 10 bit vector to which i can write to from Specman.

i was trying to do that in the `hdl_path()` but I got a VHDL compiler error when compiling the VHDL stub.

```
   keep port.hdl_path="A & B"
```

where A and B are 5 bit `std_logic_vectors`.

Comment: In VHDL a port actual is either a named signal or slice thereof, a static expression or a value derived from single signal parameter conversion function.  Essentially it has to be associated with a single named object of signal class.  The input to the VHDL analyzer (compiler) would be telling.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to connect a simple_port to a concatenation of HDL signals is supported when using verilog, using the hdl_expression() port attribute.
This even appears in the hdl_expression() document:

http://support.cadence.com/wps/mypoc/cos?uri=deeplinkmin:DocumentViewer;src=pubs;q=/sn_integ/sn_integ14.1/vlog_hdl_expr_simple.html

However, the hdl_expression() port attribute is not supported in ports that have a VHDL agent.
A way to work around this is by defining two simple ports each with the appropriate vector size as shown in this example:

```
p0: out simple_port of uint(bits:5) is instance;
p1: out simple_port of uint(bits:5) is instance;
keep p0.hdl_path()=="bus1"; 
keep p1.hdl_path()=="bus2"; 

p_top:uint(bits:10);

event write_to_p_top is change(p_top)@sys.any;

on write_to_p_top {
        p1$=p_top[4:0];
        p2$=p_top[9:5]
    };
```

In your code, all you need to do is to assign values to the top variable 'p_top'.
this will trigger the writing sequence to the actual ports with the appropriate values.

Note : this could be generalized to any number of ports using a list of simple_port